# Angular: ErrorHandler don't show error into MatDialog when error come from html template

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want intercept all errors into Angular application and show a MatDialog.

I have made a ErrorHandler

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorHandlerService },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**error-handler.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ErrorHandlerService extends ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private ngZone: NgZone) {
    super();
  }

  handleError(err: any): void {
    console.error(err);
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.dialog.open(AlertDialog, {
        data: { icon: 'Error', message: err.message, buttonText: 'Uh oh!' },
      });
    });
  }
}
```

It don't works if error come from HTML template:

[image]

MatDialog don't render the dialog if the error is into the template

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u4lxpv

Comment: It's working as expected. What you're seeing is the alert being recreated each change detection cycle (because the template is still broken): [the console shows the errors happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZI2d.png).

Comment: If you fix the template, you'll see the dialog you expect: [an error after the template is no longer broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZrns.png).

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to let the template throw errors. It's easier to protect against them (using things like `ngIf` and safe access operators `foo?.bar`) than it would be to detect the error, stop change detection for the component, show an error, fix the issue, and reenable change detection for the component.